# How can I "natively" store hexagonal grids in R?

Tags: r, matrix, coordinate-systems, r-grid, hexagonal-tiles

If I want to save some **square** grid in R, that's easily done.

Say,

```
|    | 0    | 1     | 2     |
|----|------|-------|-------|
| 0  | TRUE | TRUE  | FALSE |
| 1  | NA   | FALSE | TRUE  |
| 2  | TRUE | TRUE  | FALSE |
```

is stored as cartesian coordinate system

```
m <- matrix(data = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, NA, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE), nrow = 3, ncol = 3, byrow = FALSE)
```

and existing methods and math work as expected:

```
apply(X = m, MARGIN = 2, FUN = "sum")
# [1]  2 NA  2
print(m)
#      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
#[1,]  TRUE    NA  TRUE
#[2,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
#[3,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

(I know I can also `reshape2::melt` this into long form, but I like it wide, because that's what the UI looks like).

So far so good, familiar, intuitive.

---

Now enter the **hexagonal** grid.

[image: some grid]

I understand from [Amit Patel's marvellous/authoritative introduction to hex grids](http://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/) that I really ought to save such a grid using a *cube coordinate system*, as in the above example, because otherwise (= with 2d cartesian coordinates plus offsets) linear algebra operations don't work anymore, and general code grossness ensues.
I get that (I think).

[image: Cube coordinate system]

(For more details, again, see Amit Patel's fantastic [explainer](http://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/#coordinates)).

Entering this data in *wide* form via `array()` seems completely bonkers, because many cells don't even exist (and `NA` is already used).
So I enter/store this in long form, like so:

```
df <- rbind(c(1, 0, -1, FALSE), 
        c(0, 1, -1, NA),
        c(1, -1, 0, TRUE),
        c(0, 0, 0, TRUE),
        c(-1, 1, 0, FALSE),
        c(0, -1, 1, NA),
        c(-1, 0, 1, TRUE))
colnames(df) <- c("y", "x", "z", "value")
df
#      y  x  z value
#[1,]  1  0 -1     0
#[2,]  0  1 -1    NA
#[3,]  1 -1  0     1
#[4,]  0  0  0     1
#[5,] -1  1  0     0
#[6,]  0 -1  1    NA
#[7,] -1  0  1     1
```

This dataframe has all the data, but doesn't "know" in any way, that `x`, `y` and `z` are diagonal coordinates.

How can I:

1. store this in a *wide* form where I can easily use linear and matrix algebra,
2. use established methods (say, `colSums()`, or `apply()`)
3. as well as conveniently `print` to something like this:

[image: screenshot]

(SE won't even properly highlight this printed hex grid, hence the screenshot.)

What, in short, would be the elegant / recommended / canonical way to **"natively" store such a hexagonal grid** in R?

I am vaguely aware that I could probably implement my own S3 OO for this, though I was hoping that this might already exist in some form or another.
I *did* find lots of packages that do hex *binning* on continuous data, but they didn't seem to deal with *storing* hex grids, or at least didn't expose those internals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. store this in a wide form where I can easily use linear and matrix
    algebra**

Probably, the axial coordinates mentioned in http://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/#coordinates are the best choice here. This could give the option to convert to a standard ij-matrix with i=x and j=y, you just have to specify what to put into the matrix-cells which are not covered by your hex-grid (your own "NA"). Then you can operate along the dimension x and y as usual and have a matrix with just empty triangular upper right and lower left triangles. (This is not bonkers, but the natural way. At best you have to find a different solution for your NA in the your data. Sorry for not fiddling out the code for your example.)

**2. use established methods (say, colSums(), or apply())**

Using the dplyr package you can

`df %>% as_data_frame() %>% group_by(x) %>% summarize(sum(value))`

to sum for fixed x or the like.

**3. as well as conveniently print**

I don't have a solution for print, but displaying labels with ggplot2 can be a solution

`df %>% as_data_frame() %>% ggplot(aes(x=x+0.5*y, y=y, label=value)) + geom_text()`

Notes: The result provided here is a flipped version of what you wanted to have printed, but I hope you can find the right flip yourself. `x=x+0.5*y` serves here to give you the hex shape you are aiming at. With `x=x` you just have a skew hexagon.

**What, in short, would be the elegant / recommended / canonical way to "natively" store such a hexagonal grid in R?**

You found it already. For computation you use your df. For storage it is a bit more efficient to use the axial one. You can extract the z coordinate back easily.